# using objects.latest in DRF queryset raises error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have the following view:

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from .serializers import LocationInfoSerializer
from .models import LocationInfo


class LocationInfoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LocationInfo.objects.latest()
    serializer_class = LocationInfoSerializer
```

using this api raises the following error:

```py
TypeError at /locations/
'LocationInfo' object is not iterable
```

But if I change the queryset to:

```py
class LocationInfoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LocationInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LocationInfoSerializer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*ModelViewSet* waiting provide iterable objects. But *latest()* method returns a single object. So, you get error when you use *latest()*. If you want to return single object, you can use pk fields in *filter()* method and return querset that has a single object and iterable.

```
class LocationInfoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LocationInfoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return LocationInfo.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])# you can change this filter logic, but you must return iterable objecs here
```

If you want to return only single object fields, you can use [generics.RetrieveAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#retrieveapiview)

Comment: I didn't quite understand, could you maybe give code as explanation?

Comment: @yovelcohen I updated my answer. ModelViewSet class takes iterable objects, you can return Queryset (it is iterable) with filter method.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing:

```py
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from .serializers import LocationInfoSerializer
from .models import LocationInfo


class LocationInfoViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = LocationInfo.objects.filter(id=1).values()
    serializer_class = LocationInfoSerializer

    data = queryset.reverse()[0]
    serialized_data = LocationInfoSerializer(data, many=False)
    points = serialized_data.data.values()
```